# Why doesn't the angular2 radio module render properly?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-module

I am trying to use the MdRadioModule in my application however I must be missing a step.  I've pasted my app.module.ts, app.component.html.  My web pack bundle is valid and there are no errors in the console.

This is my import statement in my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdIconModule } from '@angular2-material/icon';
import { MdIconRegistry } from '@angular2-material/icon';
import { MdRadioModule } from '@angular2-material/radio';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdRadioModule
  ],
  providers: [ MdIconRegistry ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my app.component.html:

```
<div class="app-content">
  <md-radio-group>
    <md-radio-button value="option_1">1</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button value="option_2">2</md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to update to the latest dependecies:
`"@angular/material": "2.0.0-alpha.10",`

There is a lot of nice changes (ie, everything in one module)

Then you can simply:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule,
  ]
})
```